# How do I get the sum of all elements >10 in a given list using chez scheme?

Tags: list, vector, sum, scheme, chez-scheme

If create a chez scheme ex which makes SUM of all elements from **lista_de_elemente**

```
(define lista_de_elemente (list 2 4 1 12 32 3 34 12))

(define suma
    (lambda()
        (apply + lista_de_elemente)))
```

How do I make the sum of only elements greater than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general technique is to first form the list of elements you want to process. You already have this list. Then, you want to apply one or more transformations to the input list. In this case, we don't need to make any transformations. Then, you filter the list to only get elements that satisfy a certain condition. Finally, you apply operations that combine elements in the filtered list.

This general way of processing lists is described in [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) as

```
enumerate -> transform (map) -> filter -> accumulate
```

Now, in this case, we **don't** need to  *enumerate or map*  anything because we already have our input list as I mentioned earlier.

```
(define (filter predicate sequence) (cond
   ((null? sequence) '())
   (else (cond
   ((predicate (car sequence)) (cons (car sequence) (filter predicate (cdr sequence))))
   (else (filter predicate (cdr sequence)))))))



(define (accumulate op initial sequence) (cond
                   ((null? sequence) initial)
                   (else (op (car sequence) (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence))))))


(define (sum-list list) (accumulate + 0 (filter (lambda(x) (cond ((> x 10) #t) (else #f)))list)))


(sum-list (list 1 2 3 45 12))
;Output: 57
```

The `predicate` is just a condition that evaluates to true or false.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you may want to generalize it a little so I made `filter-sum` such that you can do this:

```scm
#!r7rs                                ; #!r6rs for r6rs
(import (scheme)                      ; replace scheme with rnrs for r6rs
        (only (srfi :1) filter fold)) ; remove filter for r6rs

;; I renamed you list
(define *lista-de-elemente* '(2 4 8 10 12 14 16))

(define (suma)
  (define (>10? x)
    (> x 10))

  (filter-sum >10? *lista-de-elemente*)) 

(suma) ; ==> 42
```

Here are some possible versions of `filter-sum`. 
We have the straight forward recursive way:

```scm
(define (filter-sum predicate lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((not (predicate (car lst))) (filter-sum predicate (cdr lst)))
        (else (+ (car lst) (filter-sum predicate (cdr lst))))))
```

But it's not very good since the order or the numbers are not important. We can do this tail recursively with an accumulator, here with a named `let` instead of an axillary procedure:

```scm
(define (filter-sum predicate lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)(acc 0))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (cdr lst) 
              (if (predicate (car lst))
                  (+ acc (car lst))
                  acc)))))
```

Now such loops with tail recursion and an accumulator can be converted to a fold. You find fold in the [SRFI-1 list library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html):

```scm
(define (filter-sum predicate lst)
  (fold (lambda (x acc)
          (if (predicate x)
              (+ acc x)
              acc))
        0
        lst))
```

Most of the code now is if you should add or not. With `filter` you can filter out so that every element in the fold can be added:

```scm
(define (filter-sum predicate lst)
  (fold + 0 (filter predicate lst)))
```

`filter` is also in the SRFI-1 List library. Now if you know your list of number above 10 is short.. Like a few hundreds you can totally change `fold` to an `apply` and it might even become a little faster, but you are making a restrictions on the length of the list. (Many scheme systems push arguments on a limited size stack while a fold will accumulate the list one element at the time.)

Answer (score 1):

By using `filter`:

```
(define suma
  (lambda()
    (apply + (filter (lambda (e) (> e 10)) lista_de_elemente))))
```

BTW, `suma` should have the list as an argument:

```
(define suma
  (lambda(lst)
    (apply + (filter (lambda (e) (> e 10)) lst))))

(suma lista_de_elemente)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function that returns a list by filtering out the numbers that are not greater than 10. Pass the return value of that to `apply` as you have.

```
(define (get-greater-than-ten lst)

  (define (helper in out)
    (if (null? in)
      out
      (if (> (car in) 10)
        (helper (cdr in) (append out (list (car in))))
        (helper (cdr in) out)))

  (helper lst `()))
```

Use it like:

```
(define suma
    (lambda()
        (apply + (get-greater-than-ten lista_de_elemente))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain a generalized `suma`, rather than defining a suma that incorporates the filter, you can instead define a suma that just sums, and then filter your list as you pass it as a parameter:

```
(define elems (list 2 4 1 12 32 3 34 12))

(define (suma lst)
  (apply + lst))

(suma (filter (lambda (x) (> x 10)) elems))
```

Now you've got your generalized `sum`, and you pass it only the portion of the original list that you intend to sum.